# Como puedo incluir todos mis sass en webpack

Tags: webpack, gulp, gulp-sass

como puedo incluir todos mis archivos sass en webpack

con gulp lo hacia de esta forma

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
 // Theme
 gulp.src('./assets/scss/**/*.scss')
  .pipe(changed('./assets/css/'))
  .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'expanded' }))
  .on('error', sass.logError)
  .pipe(autoprefixer([
      "last 1 major version",
      ">= 1%",
      "Chrome >= 45",
      "Firefox >= 38",
      "Edge >= 12",
      "Explorer >= 10",
      "iOS >= 9",
      "Safari >= 9",
      "Android >= 4.4",
      "Opera >= 30"], { cascade: true }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css/'))
  .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

y para migrarlo a webpack si o si nesesito incluir 1 x 1 ?
alguna idea.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el plugin https://github.com/maoberlehner/node-sass-magic-importer

y usarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
@import: 'scss/**/*.scss';
```